# sed awk: replace string A in lines matching string B

Tags: regex, awk, replace, sed

I´m trying to replace a string A in a line containing an other string B, which has to be found (there is variable content between A and B, anyfile.html).
Example:

```
font-size: 14px;"><a href="differentfilenames.html">1</a><br>
```

should be replaced by

```
font-size: 14px; background-color: rgb(51, 204, 255);"><a href="differentfilenames.html">1</a><br>
```

Is there a solution with bash / sed / awk?

What I ment ...
- Imagine a matrix with cells, containing numbers - 1 in the example mentioned above
- The numbers are anchors to different files; even number 1 is linked to different files. differentfilenames.html is a variable string containing letters and numbers
- Cells should get background colors in dependence of the number they contain
- So: all cells containing 1 as an anchor should get background color as above

I try to find a solution to be able to search for string B - `1</a><br>` in this case, and - if true - replace string A

```
font-size: 14px;">
```

with

```
font-size: 14px; background-color: rgb(51, 204, 255);">
```

Sorry, my first questions was not escaped correctly; I think it should be more clear now ...

Comment: you know that html codes could be broken into lines, right? then you know the risk of handling html with regex(awk,sed...)

Comment: What should A and B be? What is your "variable content"? It seems you try in insert something -- I don't see any replacement... What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a static input where newlines are distributed in the manner you want. Like Kent commented about, this could easily break.

Here's a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 'if (/1<\/a>/) { s/font-size: 14px;">/font-size: 14px; background-color: rgb(51, 204, 255);">/ }' yourfile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you need (uses GNU awk for 3rd arg to `match()`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { split("rgb(51,234,567) rgb(52,345,678) rgb(53,456,789)",m) }
match($0,/(font-size: 14px;)("><a href="differentfilenames.html">([[:digit:]]+)<\/a><br>)/,a) {
    print a[1], "background-color:", m[a[3]] ";" a[2]
}

$ cat file
font-size: 14px;"><a href="differentfilenames.html">1</a><br>
font-size: 14px;"><a href="differentfilenames.html">3</a><br>
font-size: 14px;"><a href="differentfilenames.html">2</a><br>
font-size: 14px;"><a href="differentfilenames.html">3</a><br>

$ awk -f tst.awk file
font-size: 14px; background-color: rgb(51,234,567);"><a href="differentfilenames.html">1</a><br>
font-size: 14px; background-color: rgb(53,456,789);"><a href="differentfilenames.html">3</a><br>
font-size: 14px; background-color: rgb(52,345,678);"><a href="differentfilenames.html">2</a><br>
font-size: 14px; background-color: rgb(53,456,789);"><a href="differentfilenames.html">3</a><br>
```

but I had to make up my own testable input since you didn't provide a representative set so it's a guess and you'll probably need to massage it yourself for whatever your real input looks like.